# Intersection of the circles of Apollonius

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Given triangle $\triangle ABC$. Consider an Apollonius circle $\omega_1$ of segment $AB$ with ratio $BC:CA$, i.e. for all points $X$ of this circle, we obtain: $\frac{XA}{XB}=\frac{BC}{CA}$. We define the Apollonius circle $\omega_2$ for segment $BC$ analogously - for all points $Y\in\omega_2$, we obtain: $\frac{YB}{YC}=\frac{CA}{AB}$. Prove, that if $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ do intersect, then both of the points of intersection lay on the Euler line of triangle $\triangle ABC$, in other words, that the Euler line of $\triangle ABC$ is the radical axis of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$.

I don't know how to make use of the Euler line at all and would be really, really grateful for any hints or solutions :)

Comment: Interesting problem, what have attempted? Some thoughts: If $P$ lies both on $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ then $\frac{PA}{PB}=\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{PB}{PC}=\frac{b}{c}$, hence $(PA,PB,PC)=\lambda(a,b,c)$. 
Let $P_A,P_B,P_C$ be the symmetric of $P$ with respect to the lines $BC,AC,AB$. In the hexagon $AP_C B P_A C P_B$ the sides sharing a vertex of the original triangle have the same length, and the angles at $A,B,C$ equal $2A,2B,2C$. In particular the sides of the pedal triangle of $P$ are $(\lambda a \sin A,\lambda b \sin B,\lambda c \sin C)$.

Comment: By computing the area of $P_A P_B P_C$ through Heron's formula and by imposing that the area of the outer hexagon equals twice the area of $ABC$ we may compute $\lambda$ in a explicit way, then the trilinear or barycentric coordinates of $P$ and prove that $P$ lies on the Euler line.

Comment: Or we may simply locate the centers $O_1,O_2$ of $\omega_1,\omega_2$ and prove that $H,O$ have the same powers with respect to $\omega_1,\omega_2$. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520469/apollonius-circle-its-radius-and-center) is useful, in such a case.

Comment: You may also exploit this obscure lemma: the circle inversion with respect to the circumcircle preserves the tripolar coordinates.

Comment: Additionally, this problem has already been studied by Halbrecht Hess in *Forum Geometricorum, Volume 15, 2015: Transforming Tripolar into Barycentric Coordinates*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts/hints. I'll try to make a use of them...