# If $c >0$, $c≠ 1$, $z_1≠z_2$, prove that $\frac{|z-z_1 |}{|z-z_2 | }=c$ represents a circle. Find its center and radius.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am studying complex analysis, and I was solving some questions regarding the subject when I stumbled upon this question. The equation above represents a circle, where $c$ is an arbitrary complex number. I don't get how it represents a circle, I tried proving it but I failed. Any help in finding the radius and center and proving the equation?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $|z-z_1|=c$ is a circle of radius $c$ and center $z_1$

Comment: You might want to look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520469/apollonius-circle-its-radius-and-center?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

$|z-z_{0}| = c $ then the center of the circle is $z_{0}$ and radius c.
$| \frac{z-z_{1}}{z-z_{2}}|=c$, assumed $c>0$
$\Rightarrow |z-z_{1}|=|(z-z_{2})|c$, assumed $c>0$
$\Rightarrow |z-z_{1}|-|(z-z_{2})|c=0$, assumed $c>0$
$\Rightarrow |z-cz-(z_{1}-z_{2}c)|=0 $ consider $|a|-|b|=0 \Rightarrow |a-b|=0$ where $a,b>0$ as well as assumed few additional condition.
$\Rightarrow |z(1-c)-(z_{1}-z_{2}c)|=0 $
$\Rightarrow |z(1-c)|=|(z_{1}-z_{2}c)| $consider $|a-b|=0 \Rightarrow |a|-|b|=0$ where $a,b>0$ as well as assumed few additional condition.
$\Rightarrow |z-0|=\frac{|(z_{1}-z_{2}c)|}{|1-c|}=c_{1}(say) $
Then the center of the circle is (0,0) and radius is $\frac{|(z_{1}-z_{2}c)|}{|1-c|}=c_{1}$ where $0<c<1$ is also considered.

Comment: can we distribute modulus over subtraction?? i remember modulus can be distributed over add and multiplication

Answer (score 1):

Here's a geometric way to answer this question. Everything that follows refers to the following [figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#/media/File:Apollonius_circle_definition_labels.svg) where we identify $A=z_1$, $B=z_2$ and we have used $$\frac{|z-z_2|}{|z-z_1|}=c$$

It is clear from the definition of the circle by Apollonius that the given equation is a circle, since it restricts the points $z$ of the plane to those whose distances from two given foci, situated at $z_1,z_2$.

Now that we know that the locus in question is a circle, consider the points $C,D$ of the figure. For those points it is true that:

$$\frac{|AC|}{|BC|}=\frac{|AD|}{|BD|}=c$$

However it is true $|AC|+|BC|=|z_2-z_1|$. We conclude that

$$|AC|=x =\frac{|z_2-z_1|}{1+c}~,~|BC|=y=\frac{c|z_2-z_1|}{1+c}$$

Furthermore it is true that $|AD|=2R+|AC|$, while $|BD|=2R-|BC|$ and using the ratio of these two distances we can see that the radius of the circle is (consider both cases c>1, and c<1):

$$\frac{2R+x}{2R-y}=c\iff R=\frac{c}{|1-c^2|}|z_2-z_1|$$

Now it is obvious that the center of the circle is in the same line as the two foci, and thus there has to be a constant $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$z_c=z_1+\lambda(z_2-z_1)$$

Note that in the figure $\lambda>0$ and therefore $c<1$. All we need to know is the distance $|z_c-z_1|$. We can find it in terms of known quantities because $|z_c-z_1|=x+R=\frac{|z_1-z_2|}{|1-c^2|}$ (again we need to separate the cases $c>1$ and $c<1$). Now since

$$|\lambda|=\frac{|z_c-z_1|}{|z_2-z_1|}\Rightarrow |\lambda|=\frac{1}{|1-c^2|}$$

we conclude that the position of the center is

$$z_c=z_1+\frac{1}{1-c^2}(z_2-z_1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $c$ is a real number, let  $$z=x+yi,z_1=x_1+y_1i,z_2=x_2+y_2i$$ where all the $x$'s and $y$'s are real.  Multiply both sides of your given equation by $z-z_2$ which gives $$(x-x_1)+(y-y_1)i=c((x-x_2)+(y-y_2)i)$$ Take the conjugate on both sides and multiply.Thus $$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=c^2((x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2)$$ Elementary algebra will put this equation into the standard form of a circle.

Comment: and what turns out to be the center and radius of this equation? is z1 the center and c is the radius??

Comment: x^2 +2((x1-c^2x2)/(c^2-1))x +y^2 +2((y1-c^2y2)/(c^2-1))y=(x1^2+y1^2-c^2(x2^2+y2^2))/(c^2-1). You can complete the sqare in x and y and put the equation in the form (x+((x1-c^2x2)/(c^2-1)))^2 +(y+((y1-c^2y2)/(c^2-1)))^2=K. The cenre is (-(x1-c^2x2)/(c^2-1),-(y1-c^2y2)/(c^2-1)=-(x1-c^2x2)/(c^2-1)-(y1-c^2y2)/(c^2-1)i. After you have worked out K, the radius is the square root of K.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy$, $z_1=x_1+iy_1$, $z_2=x_2+iy_2$. Then the equation becomes:
\begin{eqnarray*}
|z-z_1| 
&=& 
c|z-z_2|\\
|z-z_1|^2 
&=& 
c^2|z-z_2|^2\\
(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2 
&=& 
c^2(x-x_2)^2+c^2(y-y_2)^2\\
x^2-2xx_1+x_1^2+y^2-2yy_1+y_1^2 
&=&
c^2x^2-2c^2xx_2+c^2x_2^2+c^2y^2-2c^2yy_2+c^2y_2^2\\
x^2(1-c^2)-2x(x_1-c^2x_2)+y^2(1-c^2)-2y(y_1-c^2y_2)
&=&
c^2(x_2^2+y_2^2)-(x_1^2+y_1^2)\\
x^2-2x\left(\frac{x_1-c^2x_2}{1-c^2}\right)+y^2-2y\left(\frac{y_1-c^2y_2}{1-c^2}\right)
&=&
\left(\frac{c^2(x_2^2+y_2^2)}{1-c^2}\right)-\left(\frac{x_1^2+y_1^2}{1-c^2}\right)\\
x^2-2x\left(\frac{x_1-c^2x_2}{1-c^2}\right)+\left(\frac{x_1-c^2x_2}{1-c^2}\right)^2+y^2-2y\left(\frac{y_1-c^2y_2}{1-c^2}\right)+\left(\frac{y_1-c^2y_2}{1-c^2}\right)^2
&=&
\left(\frac{c^2(x_2^2+y_2^2)}{1-c^2}\right)-\left(\frac{x_1^2+y_1^2}{1-c^2}\right)+\left(\frac{x_1-c^2x_2}{1-c^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y_1-c^2y_2}{1-c^2}\right)^2\\
\left(x-\left(\frac{x_1-c^2x_2}{1-c^2}\right)\right)^2+\left(y-\left(\frac{y_1-c^2y_2}{1-c^2}\right)\right)^2
&=&
\left(\frac{c^2(x_2^2+y_2^2)}{1-c^2}\right)-\left(\frac{x_1^2+y_1^2}{1-c^2}\right)+\left(\frac{x_1-c^2x_2}{1-c^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y_1-c^2y_2}{1-c^2}\right)^2\\
\left(x-\left(\frac{x_1-c^2x_2}{1-c^2}\right)\right)^2+\left(y-\left(\frac{y_1-c^2y_2}{1-c^2}\right)\right)^2
&=&
\frac{c^2(x_2-x_1)^2+c^2(y_2-y_1)^2}{(1-c^2)^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
So the center appears to be $z_c=\frac{z_1-c^2z_2}{1-c^2}=z_1+\frac{c^2(z_1-z_2)}{1-c^2}$ with radius 
$$
r=\sqrt{\frac{c^2(x_2-x_1)^2+c^2(y_2-y_1)^2}{(1-c^2)^2}}=\frac{c}{|1-c^2|}|z_2-z_1|
$$
Recall that $c>0$, $c\neq 1$.

Funny; there are several answers to this question and each are different!

Comment: exactly!! i and my peer solved this question and we both got different answers tho we started out with the same way you did ! thanks for the help .

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the given equation $\frac{|z-z_1 |}{|z-z_2 | }=c$ as

$$(z-z_1)(\bar z-\bar z_1 )=c^2 (z-z_2 )(\bar z-\bar z_2 ) $$

which leads to

$$|z |^2-\frac{ z_1-z_2 c^2}{1-c^2}\bar z -\frac{ \bar z_1-\bar z_2c^2}{1-c^2}z
= \frac{ |z_2|^2 c^2 -|z_1|^2}{1-c^2}$$

or explicitly in the form of the circle equation
$$\bigg|z -\frac{ z_1-z_2 c^2}{1-c^2}\bigg|^2
= \left(\frac{ | z_1-z_2 | c}{1-c^2}\right)^2$$

Thus, the center is $ \frac{ z_1-z_2 c^2}{1-c^2}$ and the radius 
$\frac{ | z_1-z_2 |c}{|1-c^2|}$.