# What does $2|z+3i|=|z-i|$ represent?

Tags: complex-numbers

> $z$ is a complex number. What does $2|z+3i|=|z-i|$ represent?

Putting $z=x+iy$, I get a circle with radius $\frac83$. But the equation of circle is $|z-z_1|=r$.

How to intuitively see that $2|z+3i|=|z-i|$ represents a circle?

Comment: This is a disguise of the [circles of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius). I haven't tried to figure out an intuitive explanation for this, but this keyword will certainly be helpful for googling your question.

Comment: Once you square and simplify, the coefficient of $x^2$ equals the coefficient of $y^2$, and there is no $xy$, so it will be a circle

Comment: If you know that inversion preserves circles, then it suffices to check that the image of the locus under the transformation $w=\frac{1}{z-i}$ is also a circle, which is much easier to check.

Comment: @SangchulLee That's an interesting line of thinking. Mind developing that into an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Since this posting is locked, I added my answer to the linked post, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3950906/9340).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the [Circles of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius). In fact, if $|z - a| = k |z - b|$, we have
$$
\left |z - \frac{a - b k^2}{1 - k^2}\right | = \frac{k|a - b|}{|1 - k^2|},
$$
Thus it is a circle. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3881413/597771).